# Как заставить Jekyll на Github Pages компилить Jade (Pug)?

Tags: jade, jekyll, pug

Собственно, вопрос, можно ли обойтись без Коалы или другого препроцессора?
И нужно ли?

Comment: А вам с какой целью? На Github Pages? Или для самостоятельной сборки с Jekyll?

Comment: @D-side, Базы и php использоваться не будут, поэтому на Гитхабе он будет размещен, да.

Ну а вообще странный вопрос. Чем отличается процесс сборки самостоятельной от сборки с ориентацией на Гитхаб?
Процесс один и тот же, вопрос только в сложности реализации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Нет**, без препроцессора перед коммитом вы не обойдётесь. Разве что будете рендерить Jade прямо в браузере, что для статического сайта мне видится странным подходом.

На Github Pages сайты на Jekyll собираются в "безопасном режиме" [с заранее заданным набором плагинов](https://pages.github.com/versions/), поэтому выполнять там произвольный код (например, из собственных плагинов) не получится.

Так что **сам гитхаб рендерить Jade не будет**.

Разумеется, если вы готовы забить на сборку сайта гитхабом и собирать сайт вне него (локально или через CI-сервис вроде Travis), используя гитхаб только для *публикации* (но не сборки), тогда можно вытворять абсолютно что угодно.

Comment: Ага, теперь понятно. Спасибо!

Ещё есть такой вопрос: вы дали ссылку на плагины, которые есть на Гитхабе и они уже будут работать, как только я загружу в репозиторий свой сайт?
Также я там нашел в списке Sass и Liquid, с которыми я знаком. Они также будут компилироваться Jekyll при любом изменении в файлах и загружаться в готовую _site директорию?

Просто для понимания, как оно работает, интересно)

Но скорее всего лучший способ для верстки своего проекта будет загружать его через приложение Гитхаба новую версию сайта, это делается одной кнопкой, не особо же не затратно, наверно...

Comment: @VostokSisters Liquid же, пишите, в основе Jekyll. Система лэйаутов опирается на него. Естественно, он там есть :D А с Sass ситуация поинтереснее. Проще [показать пример](https://github.com/D-side/d-side.github.io/blob/master/assets/paper.sass), который на гитхабе работает.

Comment: не много понял из примера...
По поиску на Гитхабе не удалось найти файл paper.css, то есть он не скомпилился? Ну или используется где-то в общем другом sass-файле? Хотя он сам выглядит как выходной на компиляцию, осталось только в main.sass вынести... Но в мейне нет его. А самого main.css не компилируется 
Не понимаю структуру сайта, вообщем. :D Можете объяснить его?) Или вы вообще хотите сказать, что Гитхабу не нужно компилировать sass?

Comment: @VostokSisters его нет в репозитории, гитхаб собирает его сам и [раздаёт](http://dside.ru/assets/paper.css).

Comment: ну офигеть теперь. Даже и не знаю, лучше так или нет... Но определенно нужно это для себя решить) Спасибо за разъяснения